# how do i avoid android textview overlapping with the edittext

Tags: android, xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.salu.xyz.SurroundingsPropertyFragment">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView77"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Property Surroundings:"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText55"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView77"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView78"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Class Of Locality:"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView77"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView78"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText55" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView79"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Proximities to Civic Amenities:"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView78"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText57"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView79"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView80"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Neighbourhood:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView79"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText58"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView80"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText57" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hi, I'm new to Android Application Development, I am creating a form in `Fragment` which has both `TextView` and `EditText` and I was Testing it for 5-inch screens, but the `TextView`and `EditText` got overlapped.

I tried widgets to resize them but the alignment looks bad once I go towards higher screen size.

Is there a way this can be rectified or avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **linearlayout** for forms and keep the parent layout to **RelativeLayout**. Do something like this and your form will be fine on every device:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.salu.libravaluation.SurroundingsPropertyFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView77"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Property Surroundings:"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText55"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView78"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Class Of Locality:"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView79"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Proximities to Civic Amenities:"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText57"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView79" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView80"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Neighbourhood:"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText58"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```